Ceiling fan makes noise on high speed after using lamp string
I have a 3-speed ceiling fan installed on a sloped ceiling. The unit has an extension from mount to fan which is about 2 feet. It was installed 2 years ago. When the fan is set to lowest and middle speed, it doesn't make any noise. When it is set to high, it sometimes is quiet, but other times, it makes a noise I associate with the fan wobbling or vibrating. I think the wobble has to do with how much the light switch on the unit itself is used to turn the lamp on and off. When it makes a bunch of noise, I can usually tap it a few times until it stops making noise. Then it stays still, even when on high, until someone uses the switch on the fan to turn on/off the lamp built into the fan. I've read about weights that can be used, but if pulling the light string is putting it off balance, I'm not sure how the weights can help.
My wall has two 2 switches and we power on fan and/or light from one of the switches. The other switch never seemed to do anything since we moved into this house a few years ago. I know nothing about wiring.
I'm guessing the unit can be wired to power the fan with one wall switch and the light with the other wall switch. I have no idea how to check what the unused 2nd wall switch currently does, but I think I'd like to use these switches for activating the fan and light independently, if someone thinks it's possible.
If the fan can't be wired to power the light from the fan separately and I still want to occasionally use the lamp on the unit by pulling the string for the light, but avoid causing the unit to wobble, is there a suggestion on how to keep the unit stable when pulling the string for the light?
I tried to find the unit on Lowes' website. This is close, but it doesn't show the one we have installed with extension. https://www.lowes.com/pd/Harbor-Breeze-Centreville-42-in-White-LED-Indoor-Flush-Mount-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-5-Blade/1000195091?idProductFound=false&idExtracted=false

You asked two questions.
Given that pulling the string triggers the wobble, the blades must not be balanced.  Fix that with the weights and the problem should go away.  Pulling the cord is not unbalancing the fan, but may be shifting its position enough to destabilize it and make the vibration more apparent.
If you want to rewire the fan, please post a separate question.  Rewiring without balancing is unlikely to result in a fan that doesn't wobble from time to time.
